# Unable to automate selection of List-box option using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation, listbox

I have been trying to use Selenium and automate book cataloging on this software called Koha. As part of the process, I need to necessarily select an 'item type' from a drop down menu (image attached)
[Koha drop-down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC2wm.png)

Now, I have tried multiple ways to go about this but all have failed:

1. Using find_element methods to click on the drop down and select an
   option - The options in the drop down are captured as empty elements for some reason (snippet of page source code attached)
   [Source code of drop-down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p30Px.png)

Code used:

```
itemElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[contains(@id,'tag_942_subfield_c')]")
opElem = itemElem.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
print([op.text for op in opElem])
print([op.value for op in opElem])
print([op.id for op in opElem])
```

Result of print statements:

```
['','','','','','','']
```

2. Execute JavaScript queries to interact with DOM - I am able to click on the drop down but a search for the list box elements returns an error (images of HTML code for page)
   [For drop-down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXWXR.png),
   [Drop-down options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goc8H.png)

Code used:

```
java_script = "document.getElementsByClassName('select2-choice')[2].click();"
browser.execute_script(java_script)
javaScript = "document.getElementsByClassName('select2-result-label')[5].click();"
browser.execute_script(javaScript)
```

Result of code:

```
Error occurred while filling in MARC fields.
Message: TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[5] is undefined
```

Anything else I could possibly try? Let me know if sharing more of the HTML code might help.

Comment: What do you want to do with the item after you select it?

Comment: Just need to select the item 'Purchased Books' - click on it essentially since the field is mandatory

Comment: Its hard to test what to don't have access to the source page however when i have trouble getting a selection i try the "full-xpath" method. Doing this in a browser is easy because you can right click and inspect page then highlight entire element and right click again to copy/copy full xpath